# Enzyme shallow not working in circleci

Tags: circleci, enzyme

I created a test using shallow that work fine locally, but when it's running in circleci in the bitbucket pull request didn't worked. When I changed the test to use mount it work fine locally and in the circleci. Any one have any idea of the reason of this?

Original test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { Dashboard } from './../Dashboard'

describe('Dashboard', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Dashboard />)

  it('has a header', () => {
    const currentHeader = wrapper.find('Header')

    expect(currentHeader.length).toEqual(1)
  })

  it('has a subHeader', () => {
    const currentSubHeader = wrapper.find('SubHeader')

    expect(currentSubHeader.length).toEqual(1)
  })

  it('has a content', () => {
    const currentContent = wrapper.find('.sn-layout__content')

    expect(currentContent.length).toEqual(1)
  })
})
```

Modified test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { Dashboard } from './../Dashboard'

describe('Dashboard', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Dashboard />)

  it('has a header', () => {
    const currentHeader = wrapper.find('.sn-layout__header')

    expect(currentHeader.length).toEqual(1)
  })

  it('has a subHeader', () => {
    const currentSubHeader = wrapper.find('.sn-layout__subheader')

    expect(currentSubHeader.length).toEqual(1)
  })

  it('has a content', () => {
    const currentContent = wrapper.find('.sn-layout__content')

    expect(currentContent.length).toEqual(1)
  })
})
```